# c for loop jump throught first

Tags: c

here is the code. the problem is that when the program runs throght the loop, it automaticly fill the first word. if I write 2. and 3. word aaaa and bbbb - output is like:

> 1-word:
>
> 2-word:aaaa
>
> 3-word:bbbb

```
 int main(){
      int i,n,g,d,count;
            char Vir[50][20] char temp[50];

printf("Juris Kondrats ||| 111RDB271 ||| 3.grupa ||| 3.variants\n");
printf("enter amount of words: \n");
scanf("%d", &g);
printf("you need insert 10 words max 10 words long\n",g);
printf("press enter");
getche();

system("cls");

for(i=0;i<g;i++)
{
     printf("\ninsertt %d-o word\n",i+1);
     gets(Vir[i]);

}      
....
```

thanks, for any help!

Comment: Never use the `gets()` function. It cannot be used safely, since it has no way to prevent storing more data than the target array can hold.

Answer (score 0):

I expect that the problem is likely due to extra characters remaining in the input stream after the 'press enter' prompt.  Namely, a line-feed.

I take it you are using a Windows platform, because you are issuing the `cls` system command.

Therefore, the 'enter' key will be translated to a carriage-return AND a line-feed character.  You have two potential problems here.

The first is that you use `scanf` to read an integer.  The user must press ENTER after that, but those characters won't be removed from the input.  I expect that it will then skip straight past the 'press enter' prompt because there are characters (two of them) in the stream.

The first will be removed by `getche()`, and the second will go straight into the first `gets` call and tell it you've just reached the end of a line, so the user has entered an empty string.

Something like that anyway.

A lame way to cure this problem would be to use `gets` instead of `getche` on the 'press enter' prompt and just give it any old string area to write to (you'll ignore the result anyway).  It's not a good solution, but anything more complicated at this point might just confuse you.